# Converter string em blob e salvar no banco

Tags: java, android, banco-de-dados, blob

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação mobile que tem um formulário onde o usuário pode anexar uma imagem, a imagem esta sendo enviada como string via rest para o servidor e será salva no banco do tipo blob, porem,estou com problema para converter de string para blob do lado da minha api.

Capturando imagem do aplicativo via camera:

```
public void tirarFoto(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if(data != null){
        Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
        if(bundle != null){
            Bitmap img = (Bitmap) bundle.get("data");
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Foto anexada", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            img.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
            foto = Base64.encodeToString(stream.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);

        }
    }
}
```

Enviando pra minha API:

```
public void registerForms() {

    final String address = frua.getText().toString().trim();
    final String district = fbairro.getText().toString().trim();
    final String city = fcidade.getText().toString().trim();
    final String email = femail.getText().toString().trim();
    final String complement = fcompl.getText().toString().trim();
    final String state = festado.getText().toString().trim();
    final String note = fobs.getText().toString().trim();
    final String countries = fpais.getText().toString().trim();
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(DenunciaActivity.this, "Aguarde um momento", "Enviando...", true, false);

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest( Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            if (response.contains("Erro")) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText( DenunciaActivity.this, "Erro ao enviar", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();

            } else {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Intent intent = new Intent(DenunciaActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                Toast.makeText( DenunciaActivity.this, "Enviado com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText( DenunciaActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                    Log.i( TAG, "Lat: " + error );
                }
            } ) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put( KEY_USERNAME, name );
            map.put( KEY_DATE, dataFormatada );
            map.put( KEY_STATE, state );
            map.put( KEY_CITY, city );
            map.put( KEY_DISTRICT, district );
            map.put( KEY_ADDRESS, address );
            map.put( KEY_EMAIL, email );
            map.put( KEY_COMPLEMENT, complement );
            map.put( KEY_COUNTRIE, countries );
            map.put( KEY_LAT, String.valueOf( latitude ) );
            map.put( KEY_LONG, String.valueOf( longitude ) );
            map.put( KEY_NOTE, note );
            map.put( KEY_STATUS, "ATIVO" );
            map.put( KEY_IMAGE, foto );
            Log.i( TAG, "Lat: " + longitude +" "+latitude);
            return map;
        }

    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue( this );
    requestQueue.add( stringRequest );
}
```

Minha API:

```
public class Services extends Controller {

public static void denuncia(@Valid String nome, String data, String rua, String bairro, String complemento,
        String cidade, String estado, String pais, String observacao, String email, String latitude,
        String longitude, Status status, String foto) {
    if (validation.hasErrors()) {
        String mensagem = "Erro ao cadastrar";
        JsonObject j = new JsonObject();
        j.addProperty("Erro", 404);
        j.addProperty("msg", mensagem);
        renderJSON(j);
    } else {
        byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(foto);
        String msgsucess = "Cadastrado com sucesso!";
        Denuncia denuncia = new Denuncia();
        denuncia.nome = nome;
        denuncia.data = data;
        denuncia.rua = rua;
        denuncia.bairro = bairro;
        denuncia.complemento = complemento;
        denuncia.cidade = cidade;
        denuncia.estado = estado;
        denuncia.pais = pais;
        denuncia.observacao = observacao;
        denuncia.email = email;
        denuncia.latitude = latitude;
        denuncia.longitude = longitude;
        denuncia.status = status;
        if(foto == null) {
            denuncia.foto = null;
        }else {
            denuncia.foto = decodedBytes;
        }
        denuncia.save();
        JsonObject j = new JsonObject();
        j.addProperty("Success", 200);
        j.addProperty("msg", msgsucess);
        renderJSON(j);
    }
}
}
```

meu model:

```
public Blob foto;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um blob na verdade para o banco de dados é um byte[], então como o tráfego da informação foi feita em base64, é só você ler este base64 e converter para byte[] fazendo o decode do mesmo.

Primeiro de tudo, adicione a apache-commons-codec no seu projeto e, depois, ao receber seu modelo JSON, você decofica o base64:

```
byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(base64String);
```

Se estiver usando Java8 no servidor, use a conversão nativa do java:

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Comment: CDS Infomatica ele da o seguinte erro: Type mismatch: cannot convert from byte[] to Blob

Comment: E se mudar o tipo do campo de Blob para byte[], e salvar?

Comment: mudando para byte[] ele retorna o erro: Value too long for column "FOTO BINARY(255)": "X'ffd8ffe000104a46494600010100000100010000ffdb0043000101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101... (50366)"; SQL statement:

Comment: binary n pode ter tamanho, por isso o erro. No seu banco de dados não tem um tipo blob, ou image? Use eles, mas deixe sem tamanho.

Comment: Como descrito na pergunta, meu banco ja esta public Blob foto;

Comment: Qual banco está usando? Pode ser um problema do ORM então.

Comment: Banco de dados local H2, pois eh somente para testes. Mas eu tenho outro model com o BLob que consigo salvar imagens anexadas no html, e salva normalmente. O pro eh so com imagens vinda do aplicativo.

Answer (score 0):

Tratando de base64 vc precisa dar atenção a pequenos detalhes, na web vc define quebra de pagina entre outras coisas, dependendo do uso, no android não é necessario fazer isso, portanto vc pode indicar no campo 'flags' o tipo da encodificação, lembrando que para cada tipo de encodificação vc deve usar o mesmo tipo para decodificar: [fonte aqui](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html)

```
String text = "somenews";
byte[] dataParaEncode = text.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
//Usar UTF-8 se vc estiver usando o charset da sua requisição como UTF-8
String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(dataParaEncode, Base64.NO_WRAP);
//User NO_WRAP para não haver quebra de paginas, mais indicado para uso quando tratar imagens em base64
```

Decodificando

```
byte[] data = Base64.decode(base64, Base64.NO_WRAP);
String textDecoded = new String(data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

No seu caso a variável `data` será seu "`Blob`"

Answer (score -1):

```
Blob blob = new SerialBlob(foto.getBytes());
denuncia.foto = blob;
```

uma opção!

```
    byte[] byteData = foto.getBytes("UTF-8");
    Blob blobData = conexao.createBlob();
    blobData.setBytes(1, byteData);
```

Comment: da o seguinte erro: Type mismatch: cannot convert from SerialBlob to Blob

Comment: ver se a sim funciona!

Comment: Fazendo desta forma você está pegando somente a representação em bytes da string, não do conteúdo em base64.

Comment: Tem alguma outra maneira mais simples de salvar a imagem vinda do apk?